# How in JS to merge in one object two json objects where the ID of on object correspond on the same ID of the second object

Tags: javascript, json

My question relates to the fact I'm querying 2 different objects from DB and the result is in JSON. I need to merge them into one.

The 2 objects have in common this two key/value `IRBId = ...` and `id = ...` and they look as an example

OBJ 1

```
{
   "data":{
      "IRBs":{
         "nodes":[
            {
               "id":"8",
               "name":"Admin ",
            },
            {
               "id":"9",
               "name":"Again",
            }
         ],
      }
   }
}
```

OBJ 2

```
{
   "data":{
      "informedConsentForms":{
         "count":3,
         "nodes":[
            {
               "id":"93",
                ...
               "IRBId":"9",
            },
            {
               "id":"92",
               ...
               "IRBId":"8",
            },
            {
               "id":"91",
               ...
               "IRBId":"8",
            }
         ],
      }
   },
```

As you will see above OBJ 2 and OBJ 1 corresponding with the same at IRBid and id.

What I need is to merge the two OBJ where `IRBId OBJ 2 === id OBJ 1`

The result I would expect after the merge is

OBJ merged

```
 {
            [{
               "id":"93",
                ...
               "IRBId":"9",
               "irb": {
                 "name":"Again ",
                 ...
               }
            },
            {
               "id":"92",
               ...
               "IRBId":"8",
               "irb": {
                 "name":"Admin ",
                 ...
               }
            },
            {
               "id":"91",
               ...
               "IRBId":"8",
               "irb": {
                 "name":"Admin ",
                 ...
            }
         ],
   },
```

I don't know how to make it looks like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the map function on the nodes in the first object to construct a new object that contains the second and first object's attributes.

```js
const obj1 = {
  "data": {
    "IRBs": {
      "nodes": [{
          "id": "8",
          "obj1": "one",
          "name": "Admin ",
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "obj1": "two",
          "name": "Again",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

const obj2 = {
  "data": {
    "informedConsentForms": {
      "count": 3,
      "nodes": [{
          "id": "93",
          "obj2": "1",
          "IRBId": "9",
        },
        {
          "id": "92",
          "obj2": "2",
          "IRBId": "8",
        },
        {
          "id": "91",
          "obj2": "3",
          "IRBId": "8",
        }
      ],
    }
  }
};
const obj1Data = obj1.data.IRBs.nodes;
const obj2Data = obj2.data.informedConsentForms.nodes;
const res = obj2Data.map(item => {
  const obj1Item = obj1Data.find(obj1Item => item.IRBId === obj1Item.id);
  return obj1Item ? { ...item, "irb": { ...obj1Item}} : { ...item};
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Array.reduce`
Logic

- Loop through second object data nodes
- Find the matching nodes from object 1 data nodes.
- Push to accumulator with required details. (I have added only the nodes that was mentioned in in Expected resut, you can add asmuch as you need.)

```js
const obj1 = {
  "data": {
    "IRBs": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "8",
          "name": "Admin ",
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "name": "Again",
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}
const obj2 = {
  "data": {
    "informedConsentForms": {
      "count": 3,
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "93",
          "IRBId": "9",
        },
        {
          "id": "92",
          "IRBId": "8",
        },
        {
          "id": "91",
          "IRBId": "8",
        }
      ],
    }
  },
};

const obj1List = obj1.data.IRBs.nodes;
const output = obj2.data.informedConsentForms.nodes.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const matchingNode = obj1List.find((item) => item.id === curr.IRBId);
  if (matchingNode) {
    acc.push({
      id: curr.id,
      IRBId: curr.IRBId,
      irb: {
        name: matchingNode.name
      }
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

i am using nested loop, try this one

```js
const obj2 = {
   "data":{
      "informedConsentForms":{
         "count":3,
         "nodes":[
            {
               "id":"93",
               "IRBId":"9",
            },
            {
               "id":"92",
               "IRBId":"8",
            },
            {
               "id":"91",
               "IRBId":"8",
            }
         ],
      }
   },
}

const obj1 = {
   "data":{
      "IRBs":{
         "nodes":[
            {
               "id":"8",
               "name":"Admin ",
            },
            {
               "id":"9",
               "name":"Again",
            }
         ],
      }
   }
}

const result = [];
const obj2Nodes = obj2.data.informedConsentForms.nodes;
for(let i = 0; i <  obj2Nodes.length; i++) {
    const obj1Nodes = obj1.data.IRBs.nodes
    for(let j = 0; j < obj1Nodes.length; j++) {
        if(obj2Nodes[i].IRBId === obj1Nodes[j].id) {
            const {id, ...reObj1Nodes} = obj1Nodes[j];
            result.push({
                ...obj2Nodes[i],
                'irb': {
                    ...reObj1Nodes
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I saw here works but on where I need this is just giving me an empty `[]`
Can you have a look at what is wrong?
https://pastebin.com/EUiyiTmk